# How to get desired current on output of relay's module

Tags: arduino, current, relay, solenoid

I'm building automatic garden watering system using

- Arduino Uno
- 5V relay module - this one https://www.amazon.co.uk/2-channel-trigger-module-JQC-3FF-S-Z-RBTMKR/dp/B01NAJ67ML, here are technical details https://www.generationrobots.com/media/JQC-3FF-v1.pdf
- Solenoid valve, I bought this one https://www.banggood.com/12-inch-DC-12V-250mA-Electric-Solenoid-Valve-Flow-Switch-p-91741.html?rmmds=myorder&cur_warehouse=CN

First of all, relay module contains in itself transistor and kick back diode included, so no need for those.

I'm concerned about the current passed to valve (I'm afraid of burning it :)), so I have a few questions:

1. On a page I posted above for valve, it said current is 250 mA. However, on a valve I got its written 12V 4.8 W. How come that current is 250 mA? We know that I = P / u = 3.8 /12 = ~ 400 mA
2. Now, I know that valve and relay should have resistance, but I could not find it. In a page I posted above for relay module it says coil resistance if 70 ohm at 5 A. Does this mean that current that comes to my valve will be 12V / 70ohm = ~180 mA  ?

3 I connected diode in place of valve Arduino - Relay module -> 1k resistor -> diode

However, when I measure  current with multimeter before the resistor (output from relay), it is around 50 mA.

I found  in Relay datasheet (posted above) that its coil power is 0.36 W. Does it means max output current from it is 0.36W/5V =  ~ 72 mA ?

Or do I divide relay coil power with 12 V since its the external voltage I'm providing to solenoid valve using Relay?

In a case 72 mA is maximum, I would still need to use a transistor with proper resistor on base to get desired current for solenoid valve...

Thanks in  advance

Comment: The relay is an electromagnetically controlled switch. Thus the contacts you expect to have a very small resistance as in milliOhms. Don’t expect the relay to regulate the current. Have you measured how much current the solenoid actually draws? I think you’re chasing ghosts at the moment.

Comment: @aldm:  If you have valves rated for 12V and you are switching 12V to them through your relay, then you don't need to worry about the current.  They'll take what they need.  Your power supply could deliver 12V and be rated for 200 amperes and it wouldn't bother the valves at all - as long as it really delivers 12V.  You might need to worry about the duty cycle (how long the valve is allowed to be turned on and how long the pause between activations has to be,) but the current shouldn't be a problem.